# Annotating an annotation with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently doing some "fancy" annotation in Matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.axis('equal')
src_pos, dst_pos = (0, 0), (1, 1)
src_patch = plt.Rectangle(src_pos, .25, .25, color='r')
ax.add_patch(src_patch)
dst_patch = plt.Circle(dst_pos, .25, color='b')
ax.add_patch(dst_patch)
arrowprops = dict(
    arrowstyle='<-', 
    connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0.3', 
    patchA=dst_patch, 
    patchB=src_patch, 
    shrinkA=1, 
    shrinkB=1)
ant = ax.annotate('', src_pos, dst_pos, arrowprops=arrowprops)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Now I'd like to add a bit of text **next to the arrow**. The output should look like:

[image]

I am interested in a general solution in which the text placement is chosen programmatically based on the renderer's choice of arrow path. E.g.,

- The text should be placed appropriately for unknown values of `src_pos` and `dst_pos`.
- The text should be placed appropriately regardless of how the `arrowprops` are set and which `connectionstyle` is used.
- I would *prefer* to not have to call `plt.draw()` until the end of the script.

Thanks!

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/tacaswell/6337457  I don't think you can do it in one call to annotate.

Comment: @tcaswell - Thanks for the pointer. As far as I'm concerned, you can insert whatever code you want to before plt.show() to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at the http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html page.  It seems that the text can be placed independently of the arrow if you know the coordinates.  Add this before the draw() command:

```
ant2 = ax.annotate('this is\nthe text\ni want\nto add', xy=(0.1, 0.8), xytext=(0.1, 0.8), horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='top')
```

In terms of a generalized solution, it would be as complex as the original annotate because there are quite a few different kinds of things that are created depending on the parameters given to annotate.  For instance if the arrowstyle is not specified then a YAArow patch instance is created.  You can call YAArow's get_path() but a path is of limited usefulness since it's more or less just a collection of points.  You would need to write a "find_middle_of_path()" which would need to take into account that paths don't necessarily need to be contiguous, and that sometimes all of the attributes of the path are not filled out by methods that use it, etc.  An example of when an arrow path would be non-contiguous would be when the middle of the arrow path is clipped by the edge of the figure.

If arrowstyle is specified then a FancyArrowPatch instance is created.  If a FancyArrowPatch is created, you can call get_path_in_displaycoord() to get the path with the same caveat as for YAArow patch path.

IMHO you are better off creating a number of rather simple routines that call annotate two times, one for the arrow and one for the text that correspond with the probably limited ways that you really want to use annotate.

Comment: Note that "I am interested in a general solution."

Comment: I may be mistaken but I don't think there is a readily available general solution to this built into matplotlib. If you want that functionality I think you would have to add it your self using this answer.

Comment: @AlexanderVanAtta: The Matplotlib renderer must store the path data for the arrow somewhere. If so, it should be straightforward to find the position of the arrow's (linear) midpoint in data coordinates and place the text there.

Comment: @BrianTheLion why would that be true? The arrow is an arc so it doesn't need to store the whole path in coordinates, only the starting point and the arc. Having an arrow doesn't imply that matplotlib trivially knows the midpoint of the arrow.

Comment: @SimeonVisser Sorry, let me clarify: I don't think matplotlib "trivially knows" the midpoint of the arrow but I'm pretty sure the midpoint can be *trivially calculated* if the arrow's path data can be obtained. Given the data accessors available in the Annotation class' source code, it seems reasonable to assume that the path data is indeed available.

Comment: As I noted in my updated answer, there is a path object created, however it's not necessarily helpful as it is just a list of visible points and must be accessed differently depending on the arrowstyle.

Answer (score 0):

There's a another option `text()` to add any text to the plot at known position.
[look at this link for extra options](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text)

```
ant1 = ax.text(0.4, 0.6, 'text')
```

This doesn't denpend on the `arrowprops`

Comment: I am looking for a *general solution* in which the positioning point is not known in advance.

Comment: You can also calculate the position of the text on the fly. since the data points must be available to plot, you can intuitively calculate where to place your text!

Comment: Unfortunately this is not true with the various "fancy" arrow styles that Matplotlib allows. See http://matplotlib.org/users/plotting/examples/connectionstyle_demo.png